# Aggregating query items with the same field value

Tags: django, django-orm, aggregation

One of my querysets returns list of items with several fields:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'John', 'products': 4}, {'name': 'John', 'products': 6}, {'name': 'Sam', 'products': 7}, ...]>
```

How do I aggregate this data to get combined `Sum()` of `products` value for elements with the same `name` field to avoid duplicates in queryset, so as a result I'll have something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'John', 'products': 10}, {'name': 'Sam', 'products': 7}, ...]>
```

I understand this should be done using `.annotate()` or `.aggregate()` queries but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct such queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Model.objects.values('name').annotate(
    sum_products=Sum('products')
).order_by('name')
```

The `.order_by(..)` is necessary to force Django to use a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I understand that `.values('name')` should be before `.annotate()` clause, but why exactly? Does it tell the query which field is used for grouping? What is general mechanism behind it?

Comment: @StanRedoute: exactly. You need to specify what values will be used in the select part. The ones in the `.annotate(..)` will automatically be added.

Comment: But why is order of `.values()` in the query so important? I noticed that if I move it to the end right before `.order_by()` - query does return slightly different result (different enough to make it unusable).

Comment: @StanRedoute: because then you will take all the values into account in the GROUP BY. Most Django operations are "order-sensitive". You can use `print(Model.objects.values(..).query)` to print the query Django will make.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `annotate`, and you can do something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

your_queryset = YourModel.objects.annotate(total_products=Sum('products')).values_list('name', 'total_products')
```

You can learn more about it by looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)